# How can we get photos of particular location from google maps in flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-maps

Can someone help me about query of retrieving photos of particular location on google maps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways to get nearby places from google.

This [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_places) might help you.

Additionally, you can try these ([google_place](https://pub.dev/packages/google_place), [google_maps_webservice](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_webservice)) packages too.

Comment: done deal, but this is not the way to ask for an upvote.